# Any website for studying English Words?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am from China, and want to use a web app to help me remember more English words.

Desired functionality:

1. Randomly select words to test the user. If the user does not pass, test again some time later.
2. Add words to a custom dictionary.
3. A mobile client would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[www.livemocha.com](http://www.livemocha.com) is good for learning languages. Granted, the interface is in English, but if you can get past that it will probably work well for you.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the bottom of the page there are links to different language versions of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I have some website reference which may help you regarding **`English Words`**:

### Websites:

---

1. http://www.englishwords.com/
2. http://www.world-english.org/
3. http://getwords.com/
4. http://www.yourdictionary.com/

### Books:

---

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=lz9YQ5rPcrcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=english+words&source=bl&ots=-M3KopBMnT&sig=DzSrVGEhSU2vkHGnGafYlAc0dIw&hl=en&ei=h-F9TKXKIoHCcfbm3McJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q&f=false

### Dictionary:

---

1. http://wordweb.info/free/
   WordWeb is a one-click English thesaurus and dictionary for Windows that can look up words in almost any program. It works off-line, but can also look up words in web references such as the Wikipedia encyclopedia.
2. http://english-words.qarchive.org/
   English Vocabulary for TOEFL/IELTS/GMAT/GRE/SAT Useful Dictionary with Grammatical notes

Hope it helps you.

Enjoy!!!

Comment: and there is [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Stack Exchange site that focuses on English:  http://english.stackexchange.com if you haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The largest dictionary of modern language on-line [Merrian-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com)

Answer (score 0):

Speak English Like an American is a great book and CD for improving your American English (http://www.languagesuccesspress.com). The company just released a new iPhone app Speak English Like an American which will help you master American English words, idioms and expressions. Very cool and helpful! For more info:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/english-at-work/id398332055?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/), which helps you learn words at your pace by asking questions in an **interesting way**. The questions asked are adaptive and the scores are tracked. The site claims

> "Vocabulary.com is the easiest, most intelligent way to improve your
> vocabulary. It combines an adaptive learning system (The Challenge)
> with the world’s fastest dictionary (The Dictionary) so that you can
> more quickly and more efficiently learn words. "

It does have a mobile application too (not free).